# Where do I get sencha sdk from?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I need sencha sdk to setup my sencha intellij plugin. When I searched for sencha sdk I got a to sencha command.

[image]

This is what my sencha command folder looks like.
[image]

What do I enter for sdk? The only sdk I can find online is for sencha touch. Cant find one for sencha desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok when they said sdk they actually meant the regular extjs download.

[image]